# quaternions transformation

Tags: rotations, quaternions, orientation, rigid-transformation

I'm working with IMU providing me with their orientation to a common global coordinate system. I have created a segment coordinate system from a static posture with know orientations. I have placed two sensors on the thigh, rotated approx. 90 degrees around global Z and 1 on the pelvis. I need to convert the sensor's orientation to the segment CS orientation.

## offsetting to 1 frame during standing

```
q_w_pelvis= q_pelvis[i]*q_pelvis[0].conjugate)
q_w_thigh1= q_thigh1[i]*q_thigh1[0].conjugate)
q_w_thigh2= q_thigh2[i]*q_thigh2[0].conjugate)
```

## rotating segment CS with sensor orientation.

```
q_segment_pelvis = q_segmentCS_pelvis*q_w_pelvis[i]*q_segment_pelvis[].conjugate)
q_segment_thigh1 = q_segmentCS_thigh1*q_w_thigh1[i]*q_segment_thigh1[0].conjugate)
q_segment_thigh2 = q_segmentCS_thigh2*q_w_thigh2[i]*q_segment_thigh2[0].conjugate)
```

I did expect thigh1 and thigh2 to result in the same segment CS of the thigh. But it's not the case. How can I achieve the same segment orientation no matter which of the two thigh sensors I use?

[image]

Comment: What is a segment orientation and segment coordinate system? Is that important to your problem?

Comment: Hi Ralff. THanks for your comment. Yes the segment orientation and segment coordinate system is important to achieve anatomical correct joint angles from the IMU. The segment orientation is the orientation of the segment coordinate system. The segment coordinate system is a coordinate system where x is aligned with the bone, z is the mediolateral axis and the y axis is the frontal axis.